# Gemfile require gem in all environments except one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I have rails application with a lot of environments: test, dev, production, staging, testing2 and so on.

I want `gem 'puma'` to be installed for all environments except test. How can I make it?

The simplest way is to make whitelist:

```
gem 'puma', group: [:development, :staging, :dev, :production, :testing2]
```

But this seems too bad, because it'll be better just to make:

```
gem 'puma', except: [:test]
```

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: sorry, there is no way to do this

Comment: @YuryLebedev please make your comment an answer

Answer (score 7):

Sorry, there is no way to do this.